# 360 Orbital Camera Controller

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rotation, orbit

I have a stationary cube in my scene that I'm orbiting a camera around. I have my MainCamera nested under a GameObject that I'm calling 'OrbitalCamera'.

I setup the script so that a click (or tap) and drag will rotate the camera around the object in space so it feels like you're rotating the cube (ie: if I click the top of a face on the cube, and pull down, I'm rotating the X value) but you'll actually be rotating the camera.

For the most part, my script works. However, after rotating the Y so much, the camera is upside down and the X gets inverted. Here's my script:

```
public class OrbitalCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool cameraEnabled;

    [SerializeField] private float touchSensitivity;
    [SerializeField] private float scrollSensitivity;
    [SerializeField] private float orbitDampening;

    protected Transform xFormCamera;
    protected Transform xFormParent;
    protected Vector3 localRotation;
    protected float cameraDistance;

    void Start () {
        cameraEnabled = true;
        xFormCamera = transform;
        xFormParent = transform.parent;
        cameraDistance = transform.position.z * -1;
    }

    void LateUpdate () {
    if (cameraEnabled) {
            // TODO:: FIX PROBLEM WHERE WHEN CAMERA IS ROTATED TO BE UPSIDEDOWN, CONTROLS GET INVERSED
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0) {
                    localRotation.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * touchSensitivity;
                    localRotation.y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * touchSensitivity;
                }
            }
        }

        Quaternion qt = Quaternion.Euler(localRotation.y, localRotation.x, 0);
        xFormParent.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(xFormParent.rotation, qt, Time.deltaTime * orbitDampening);
    }
}
```

Is there a good method to achieve this type of 360 camera? I'd like dragging from right to left to always move the camera left and dragging left to right to always move the camera right -- no matter how the camera is oriented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving question to Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550246/unity3d-c-sharp-360-orbital-camera-controller) as the GameDev Stack Exchange isn't nearly as popular. This question got me the 'tumbleweed' badge.